# Install soffit before or after new cabinet install?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, framing, cabinets

I just took down the drywall and existing soffit on my kitchen wall. I am going to install taller cabinets. What steps should I follow? Should I re-drywall now, install the cabinets, then build out a soffit above? Or should I frame out a soffit now, then drywall everything, then install the cabinets. In the soffit area, there are DMV pipes and stapled wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Just imagining the logistics of it, I wouldn't want to build a soffit above already installed cabinets, especially if there are mechanicals up there already. Not to mention, trying to protect the cabinets while you drywall, mud, sand, and paint everything would be a nightmare.

Unless you have some really compelling reason why you can't, why wouldn't you do it before the cabinet install?

Comment: I usually build soffits first and paint especially with premade cabinets, you won’t be getting them goofed up by working over them, add the trim and it is finished much quicker.

Comment: What about building the soffit itself to allow for a bit of trim/crown after I install the cabinets, should I give myself 1-2" of play, setting the soffit back a bit from where I expect the front edge of the wall cabinet to come up (assuming I can make up the difference later with trim to make everything look neat and flush)?

Comment: @jcwkjw20170 - if you have the cabinets in hand (ie, already delivered), you should be able to get the measurements you need. you could temporarily mount one to see where your soffit needs to go.